# Error occured when trying to upload file using html:file in Struts

Tags: java, jsp, struts, struts-tags

I came across a problem that when I try to upload a file in Struts using `<html:file/>`

this is part of my jsp

```
<tr>
    <td width="18%" bgcolor="#DEE3E7" align="center">
        <bean:write name="replaceAttachmentsForm" property="destId"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        Subject
    </td>
    <td width="18%" bgcolor="#DEE3E7" align="center">
         <bean:write name="replaceAttachmentsForm" property="concernedDept"/>
    </td>
    <td width="18%" bgcolor="#DEE3E7" align="center">
          <bean:write name="replaceAttachmentsForm" property="letterSubject"/>
    </td>
    <td width="18%" bgcolor="#DEE3E7" align="center">
       <html:file property="formFileLetter" name="replaceAttachmentsForm"  ></html:file>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

And this is the registered bean

```
public class ReplaceAttachmentsForm extends WebActionForm{
private FormFile formFileLetter;
private FormFile formFileAttachment;

public void setFormFileLetter(FormFile formFileLetter) {
    this.formFileLetter = formFileLetter;
}

public FormFile getFormFileLetter() {
    return formFileLetter;
}

public void setFormFileAttachment(FormFile formFileAttachment) {
    this.formFileAttachment = formFileAttachment;
}

public FormFile getFormFileAttachment() {
    return formFileAttachment;
}}
```

The problem here is that whenever I try to upload a file an exception

"Cannot invoke ae.ems.let.web.ReplaceAttachmentsForm.setFormFileLetter on bean class 'class ae.ems.let.web.ReplaceAttachmentsForm' - type mismatch - had objects of type "java.lang.String" but expected signature "org.apache.struts.upload.FormFile"

Can anyone suggest Why am I not able to upload a file using Struts tags? Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please post the complete stacktrace.

Comment: Thanks @RomanC , it turns out that missed `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute of the `<html:form/>`

Answer (score 1):

So after a bit of digging, it turns out that I missed `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute of the `<html:form/>`